# How to select content inside an array with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made an leafpad openstreetmap with marker and popups.
I now want to change a picture displayed in another `<div id="plot">` on that website depending on which marker clicked. For updating the div i thought of using jquery. My problem is now to get the content(image url) of the array when I click on a marker...
I would appreciate any help.

```
function add_marker() {
    var points = [
        ["P1", 51.57186, 11.8517, '<img src="img/1.JPG" alt="" width="350px">'],
        ["P2", 51.57886, 11.8117, '<img src="img/2.JPG" alt="" width="350px">'],
        ["P3", 51.57586, 11.8017, '<img src="img/3.JPG" alt="" width="350px">']
    ];

    var marker = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        marker[i] = new L.Marker([points[i][1], points[i][2]])
        marker[i].addTo(map);
        marker[i].bindPopup(points[i][0]);
        marker[i].on('click',  onClick);
    }

    function onClick(e) {
        $('#plot').html(points[i][3]);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass along references to `points` and `i` as arguments to your `onClick` function, as they are not within the global namespace.

```
function add_marker() {
    var points = [
        ["P1", 51.57186, 11.8517, '<img src="img/1.JPG" alt="" width="350px">'],
        ["P2", 51.57886, 11.8117, '<img src="img/2.JPG" alt="" width="350px">'],
        ["P3", 51.57586, 11.8017, '<img src="img/3.JPG" alt="" width="350px">']
    ];
    var marker = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        marker[i] = new L.Marker([points[i][1], points[i][2]])
        marker[i].addTo(map);
        marker[i].bindPopup(points[i][0]);
        marker[i].on('click', function(e){
          onClick(e, points, i);
        });
    };
};

function onClick(e, points, i) {

    $('#plot').html(points[i][3]);
};
```

Comment: That's wrong! The `i` variable will contain "points.length - 1" value for all onClick() function.

Answer (score 1):

```
function add_marker() {
    var points = [
        ["P1", 51.57186, 11.8517, '<img src="img/1.JPG" alt="" width="350px">'],
        ["P2", 51.57886, 11.8117, '<img src="img/2.JPG" alt="" width="350px">'],
        ["P3", 51.57586, 11.8017, '<img src="img/3.JPG" alt="" width="350px">']
    ];
    var marker = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        marker[i] = new L.Marker([points[i][1], points[i][2]])
        marker[i].addTo(map);
        marker[i].bindPopup(points[i][0]);
        // using a closure to avoid incorrect reference
        (function (i) {
            marker[i].on('click', function(e){
                onClick(e, points, i);
            });
        })(i)
    };
};

function onClick(e, points, i) {
    $('#plot').html(points[i][3]);
};
```

https://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/ explaining why using the closure